# JQuery load file based on filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a simple handler to open an iframe containing a video into a modal. There are now 2 videos from 2 pages. I want to reuse the function so that any file can be loaded based on the file name. I know it's simple syntax, just not sure what it is.

Link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoPopup" class="modal-link">`
```

Function:

```
$('.desktop-cta-mod .modal-link').on('click', function () {
    $('#videoPopup .modal-content').load('Content/video.html', function () {
        //bind closers
        $('.modal-backdrop, .modal-content button').off().on('click', function () {
            $('#videoPopup .modal-content').empty();
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the 2 different pages/urls as **data attribute** to your link tag and when clicked,read from the currently clicked item.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoPopup" 
                                   data-videourl="Content/video.html" class="modal-link">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoPopup"
                                   data-videourl="Content/video2.html" class="modal-link">
```

and your javascript will be

```
$('.desktop-cta-mod .modal-link').on('click', function () {
    var url=$(this).data("videourl");
    $('#videoPopup .modal-content').load(url, function () {
        //bind closers
        $('.modal-backdrop, .modal-content button').off().on('click', function () {
            $('#videoPopup .modal-content').empty();
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        });
    })
});
```

Just make sure that you are correctly rendering the url values. If Content directory is at the root level, you may use `/Content/Video.html`

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Never thought of it that way. Excellent answer.